# dedupe list object using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on a function which should dedupe (remove duplicates) from a list object. Here is the requirement:

Tradeline is considered as duplicate if it has:

- Same account number, account type, date and it's not manual

If you found something then select only those which has

- Latest reported date
- **If same reported date then compare (30,60,90) fields and select tradeline which has a higher value in ANY of the above three attributes**

I am having trouble implementing the last bullet point. Here is my code:

```
public IEnumerable<Tradeline> DedupeTradeline(IEnumerable<Tradeline> tradelines)
{
    //split tradeline into manual and non-manual    
    var tradelineDictionary = tradelines.GroupBy(x => x.Source == "MAN").ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
    //create list of non-manual tradeline for dedupe logic
    var nonManualTradelines = tradelineDictionary.Where(x => x.Key == false).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
    var manualTradelines = tradelineDictionary.Where(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();

    //check if same reported date is present for dedupe tradelines
    var duplicate = nonManualTradelines?.GroupBy(x => new
    {
        x.ReportedDate,
        x.Account,
        x.AcctType,
        x.Date
    }).Any(g => g.Count() > 1);

    IEnumerable<Tradeline> dedupe;
    if (duplicate != null && (bool) !duplicate)
    {
        //logic for dedupe tradeline if no same reported date
        dedupe = nonManualTradelines.GroupBy(x => new
            {
                x.Account,
                x.AcctType,
                x.Date
            })
            //in case of duplicate tradelines select one with the latest date reported
            .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(o => o.ReportedDate).First());
    }
    else
    {
        //logic for dedupe tradeline if same reported date
        dedupe = nonManualTradelines?.GroupBy(x => new
            {
                x.ReportedDate,
                x.Account,
                x.AcctType,
                x.Date
            })
            .Select(); 
            // Stuck here not sure what to do
    }

    //append manual tradeline to the output of dedupe tradelines
    var response = manualTradelines != null ? (dedupe).Union(manualTradelines) : dedupe;

    return response;
}
```

Tradeline class:

```
public class Tradeline
{
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public string AcctType { get; set; }
    public string Late30 { get; set; }
    public string Late60 { get; set; }
    public string Late90 { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string ReportedDate { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for a tradeline to have a higher 30 but lower 60 or 90? In those sort of cases, which has precedence?

Comment: As of now, 30/60/90 have the same precedence. For e.g, one tradeline has values like `9-9-9` and the other one has `10-0-0`. Then we should select the second one. It's looking at the higher number only.

Comment: And if it had 9-9-9 and 0-0-10 would it select the first one? Also, why are these `string`s?

Comment: It would be the second one. Logic is to select higher value irrespective of where it is present in 30/60/90. These are `string`s because I am reading them from `XML` and for simplicity point of view, haven't converted it into `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just sort descending by the maximum `Late`x value. I replaced the peculiar use of `Dictionary` with a simple and more efficient separation of the two categories.

```
public static class ObjectExt {
    public static int ToInt<T>(this T obj) => Convert.ToInt32(obj);    
}

public IEnumerable<Tradeline> DedupeTradeline(IEnumerable<Tradeline> tradelines) {
    //split tradeline into manual and non-manual    
    var nonManualTradelines = new List<Tradeline>();
    var manualTradelines = new List<Tradeline>();
    foreach (var t in tradelines) {
        if (t.Source == "MAN")
            manualTradelines.Add(t);
        else
            nonManualTradelines.Add(t);
    }

    IEnumerable<Tradeline> dedupe = nonManualTradelines.GroupBy(t => new {
                t.Account,
                t.AcctType,
                t.Date
            })
            //in case of duplicate tradelines select one with the latest date reported
            .Select(tg => tg.OrderByDescending(t => t.ReportedDate).ThenByDescending(t => Math.Max(t.Late90.ToInt(), Math.Max(t.Late60.ToInt(), t.Late30.ToInt()))).First());

    //append manual tradeline to the output of dedupe tradelines
    return dedupe.Union(manualTradelines);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Though, the 30/60/90 logic will take place only if in the group of similar tradeline identified, reported date is also the same. If it's not then select only latest reported date tradeline. I think you have missed this logic.

Comment: @Shaggy Think about the sort - if latest reported date has no duplicates, it will sort to the top. If it has duplicates, then the duplicate group at the top will sort by max Late* value.